# Suppressing WWW-Authenticate using X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest: source?

Tags: web, spring-security

[This tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) states that appending `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` to the HTTP request prevents the (spring) server from responding with a `WWW-Authenticate`.

I am wondering:

1. Is this behaviour documented? Can anyone point me to a source of reference?
2. Is it a standard or a convention in web servers? is it spring-specific?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. The best reference is the source code. In the [HttpBasicConfigurer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/HttpBasicConfigurer.java#L101) class you can see that when it's an AJAX call (i.e. the request has the header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`), a simple 401 response is returned. If it's not AJAX, then the `WWW-Authenticate` header is also added.
2. It's a common behaviour when using HTTP Basic authentication in the context of AJAX calls.  When the `WWW-Authenticate` header is included in a response, the browser shows the user a popup dialog automatically to ask for username and password. For AJAX calls, that's not the best user experience. By not using the `WWW-Authenticate` header in a response to an unauthenticated AJAX call, Spring Security gives the front-end application the option to implement a better logic to deal with the missing credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the response  Still, I was after a documentation reference. If indeed this behaviour is common, I expected at least some frameworks to mention this in their docs.

Comment: Apparently, the section of the Spring Security documentation about basic authentication doesn't include that piece of information. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-basic) Feel free to report an issue on the Spring Security GitHub project to update the docs: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues